# TypeScript get value of PromiseLike<CryptoKey>

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

How to use promiseLike in TypeScript ?
I want to use this code :

```
let key = crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: 'AES-GCM', length: 128}, true, ['encrypt,decrypt']);
let iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
crypto.subtle.encrypt({name: 'AES-GCM', tagLength: 32, iv}, key, new TextEncoder().encode(this.text));
----------------------------------------------------------- ^^^ -------------------------------------
```

How can use key in that line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way is to use async await in your code

```
async function myFn() {
/// ....
 let key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: 'AES-GCM', length: 128}, true, ['encrypt,decrypt']);
let iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
crypto.subtle.encrypt({name: 'AES-GCM', tagLength: 32, iv}, key, new TextEncoder().encode(this.text));
// ...
}
```

await "unwraps" your promises into values